# for statement: >= not working inside loop in R

Tags: r

I have the following code to count the number of values that are >= to 5.0 in one of the columns of my dataframe:

```
x <- c(0)
for (value in df6$X..Area) {
    print(value)
    if (value >= 5) {
      x  <- x + 1
      print(x)
    }
    else {
      x <- x + 0
      print(x)
    } 
  } 
print(x)
```

And it returns x=10 when I know it should be 17:

```
[1] "11.73098473"
[1] 0
[1] "0"
[1] 0
[1] "9.849058487"
[1] 1
[1] "43.2290388"
[1] 1
[1] "12.8687744"
[1] 1
[1] "0"
[1] 1
[1] "16.30132657"
[1] 1
[1] "2.034024167"
[1] 1
[1] "9.728666256"
[1] 2
[1] "6.917304127"
[1] 3
[1] "23.29546703"
[1] 3
[1] "52.92463306"
[1] 4
[1] "25.28850095"
[1] 4
[1] "2.38663933"
[1] 4
[1] "76.27067973"
[1] 5
[1] "51.24831201"
[1] 6
[1] "53.32903266"
[1] 7
[1] "50.15874772"
[1] 8
[1] "2.532038435"
[1] 8
[1] "70.50085659"
[1] 9
[1] "32.78354366"
[1] 9
[1] "53.89978124"
[1] 10
[1] "1.18394304"
[1] 10
> print(x)  
[1] 10
```

However, when I take this out of the loop and test for values individually, it returns the right answer?

```
> z <- 11.73098473
> z >= 5
[1] TRUE
```

So then why is the >= not working inside the loop? I am very new to R, can anyone help me with this, please? Thanks

Comment: you can see your problem in your print statement - your values are strings which can not be evaluated by <> or =

Comment: Do you have to do with loop though? This can be achieved by other methods such as `filter` or `count`

Comment: @TomHoel or a simple `ifelse()` but none of it will work as long as characters are evaluated

Comment: Is there a simple function to convert only one of my column values from characters to numeric?

Comment: `df6$X..Area <- as.numeric(df6$X..Area)`

Comment: df6$X..Area <- as.numeric(df6$X..Area) this returns values that have nothing to do with the original: > str(df6$X..Area)
 num [1:23] 19 1 100 79 22 1 29 32 99 91 ...

Comment: Can you please add the output of `dput(df6)` or `head(dput(df6), 100)` to your question?

Comment: I restarted Rstudio and now it is transforming the characters onto the right numericals, so it is solved now! Many thanks

Comment: @CarmenMoreno just in case you are interested in an alternative (faster) approach please check my answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A version avoiding the for-loop:

```
df6 <- data.frame(`X..Area` = as.character(runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)))
df6$X..Area <- as.numeric(df6$X..Area)
# df6$cumsum <- cumsum(df6$X..Area >= 5)
# print(df6$cumsum)

df6$gt5 <- df6$X..Area >= 5
colSums(df6[, "gt5", drop = FALSE])

# alternative:
# sum(df6$X..Area >= 5)
```

Comment: I dont know why but I don't think that works as it returns the following to me: `>print(df6$cumsum)
  [1]  1  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  8  9 10 11 12 12 13 13 14 15 16 16 17 17 17 17 18 18 19 19 19 20 21 22 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 25 26 27 27
 [48] 28 29 29 29 29 30 31 32 32 32 32 33 33 34 35 36 36 37 38 39 39 40 41 41 42 42 42 43 44 45 46 46 46 46 47 48 48 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 54 54 55
 [95] 55 55 55 56 57 57` I would like the answer to be 17, which is the number of values that are above 5 in my df column

Comment: @CarmenMoreno ok now I understand - I was trying to replicate the for-loop's print output. Please see my edit.